# How has "Unbroken" fared in Asian markets?

Tags: reception, box-office, unbroken

['Unbroken' unable to draw local audience yet](http://www.china.org.cn/arts/2015-02/05/content_34742788.htm) and [South Korea Box Office: 'Unbroken' Debuts in Fourth Place](http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/news/south-korea-box-office-unbroken-762990) seem to indicate that "Unbroken" hasn't fared particularly well in Asian markets.

[Angelina Jolie's war film faces box office challenge in Asia](http://www.scmp.com/lifestyle/arts-culture/article/1661418/angelina-jolies-war-film-faces-box-office-challenge-asia) predicted that the movie would fare well in such countries:

> Although Unbroken has yet to be approved by the mainland for release
>   there, the film will likely find an appreciative audience.
>   Hillenbrand's book has been translated into Chinese and has earned
>   largely positive reviews. Second world war movies such as Pearl Harbor
>   and Saving Private Ryan have performed strongly at the mainland box
>   office. And actress-director Jolie has a sizeable and enthusiastic
>   following there.
>
> Most important, given the history of deep animosity and conflict
>   between China and Japan, Chinese audiences have long embraced films
>   and TV series with an anti-Japanese bent. On the mainland, such films
>   are a veritable industry unto themselves: in 2012 alone, more than 200
>   were made by Chinese studios, most shown on TV.

The movie performed well in the [US and Canada](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbroken_%28film%29#Box_office).

So far, it seems the film [has not been released in Japan](http://ajw.asahi.com/article/behind_news/social_affairs/AJ201503170081), though there's suspicions that's because of political considerations.

Has the film not fared well in Asian markets, and if so, why?

Comment: It did not release in Japan; https://www.boxofficemojo.com/year/2014/?area=JP&grossesOption=calendarGrosses

Comment: It earned [pennies in Hong Kong and Taiwan](https://www.the-numbers.com/movie/Unbroken#tab=international) and a respectable million dollars in Korea. Basically it did bad.